# .htaccess redirect replacing a word not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my url's I've replaced the word "national" by "landelijke-deals"

So for example from:
`http://allthedeals.nl/deals/national/reizen-vakantie`

To:
`http://allthedeals.nl/deals/landelijke-deals/reizen-vakantie`

I'm using this:

```
RewriteRule ^national/(.*) /landelijke-deals/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to redirect, but for some reason it's not working properly, what am i not seeing?

**UPDATE: This is my current htacces file**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.allthedeals\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://allthedeals.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^deals([-a-zA-Z\/]+)?$ deals.php?vars=$1 [L,QSA]
#
RewriteRule ^deal/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ CustomDealDetail.php?dealId=$2&seo=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^deal/([0-9]+)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ old_id_redirect.php?old_id=$1&seo=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^aggdeal/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ dealdetails.php?dealId=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^deal-aanbieders$ deal-aanbieders.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^deals/national/(.*) /deals/landelijke-deals/$1 [R,L]
#RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ index.php [NC,R]
```

Comment: Firstly, I would make sure that you have `RewriteEngine On` in your VHost config/htaccess file.

Comment: yes the RewriteEngine On is in the file

Comment: Question: where are you placing this rule (inside .htaccess or vhost) and if it is inside `.htaccess` then is it the one inside the root directory or inside a physical `/deals` directory?

Comment: in .htaccess and the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule is wrong. Use the following rewrite rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/deals/national/(.*)$ /deals/landelijke-deals/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi William, that line looks right to me but for some reason it's not doing the redirect. Could this be affected by other elements in my htaccess file?

Comment: It shouldn't as long as mod_rewrite is enabled. Check that it is by looking in your httpd.conf or by running "sudo a2enmod rewrite" (for linux)

Comment: Also, it might be worth putting the entire contents of you htaccess file in your question

Comment: You don't have a RewriteBase / directive so try adding a forward slash before the deals part of the rule  i.e ^/deals...

Comment: I change it to: `RewriteRule ^/deals/national/(.*) /deals/landelijke-deals/$1 [R,L]` 
but still no luck. The page pauzes for a sec and then still goes to the old one...

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule you need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(deals)/national/(.+)$ $1/landelijke-deals/$2 [R=301,L.NC]
```